# OpenLayers WFS Multipoint

Tags: geoserver, layers, wfs, openlayers-2, multipoint

I am modifying a OpenLayers setup which uses WFS capabilities to create a vectorLayer on a map to support multipoints.

GeoServer is setup to send points and multipoints however only points are displayed. Is there a specific setting that prevents multipoints from being displayed in OpenLayers?

```
MySet.config.myLayer = {
styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(
    {
        'default': {
            cssClass: "${categorie}",
            label: "${count}",
            popupActive: "${active}"
        }
    }
),
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    url: MySet.config.WFSurl,
    featureType: "mypoints",
    geometryName: "location",
    version: "1.1.0",
    method: "GET",
    outputFormat: "GML2"

}),
maxResolution: 6.720,
minResolution: 0.210,
renderers: [MySet.Renderer.Anchor],
rendererOptions: {iconSize: MySet.config.iconSize, imgPath: MySet.config.imgPath, classificationInfo: MySet.config.classificationInfo},
strategies: [
    new MySet.Strategy.ThemeVisibility({attributeName: 'categorie'}),
    new MySet.Strategy.Sort({sortHeight: MySet.config.sortHeight}),
    new MySet.Strategy.Cluster({attributeName: 'categorie', attributeValue: 'cluster', threshold: 2, distance: 21}),
    new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()
]};
```

Draw

```
createVectorLayers : function () {
            vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(null, this.config.myLayer);
            map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
            var keys = ['prov', 'gem', 'wk'];
            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                var options = this.config.clusterLayer[keys[i]];
                var lyr = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(options.title, options);
                map.addLayer(lyr);
            }
        }
```